# Difference between two dates returned in hours,minutes,seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

The following query returns dates in terms of hours,minutes,seconds.

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),  ModifiedOn- CreatedOn, 108), 8)
AS ResultTime from AssignedRoles
```

I have an extra field in the table AssignedRoles -"TurnAroundTime" where i would like to store the result generated from the query. 
Is this method effective, or is using a trigger a better option and if so kindly explain how to undertake it.

The database is a backend to an MVC C# application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a computed column:

```
alter table AssignedRoles add 
    turnAroundtime as (left(convert(varchar(10), ModifiedOn - CreatedOn, 108), 8))
```

This gives you an always up-to-date value that you don't need to maintain manually, with almost zero extra code.

Comment: This query is working.One more thing,  how do i convert the computed column to DateTime

Comment: You can't, easily. This function produces a *string* of the form "hh:mm:ss". Datetime datatypes must have (contain?) a date; as you've stripped that out, what value should be used for the date?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @GMB (+1). However, you are storing (or calculating) this value as a formatted character string. I recommend storing it as a TIME datatype value, as that will give you more flexibility and options in the future. Let the application using this data worry about the formatting, it will do a better job of it.

```
ALTER TABLE AssignedRoles add 
 turnAroundtime as CONVERT(TIME, ModifiedOn - CreatedOn)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is limited to values less than 24 hours. SQL Server does not have a data type equivalent to a .NET [`timespan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

Comment: the following is thrown   The 'TurnAroundime' property on 'AssignedRoles' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.

Comment: @HABO, this is true. This limitation would also apply to the original structure, as it just pulls out hh:mm:ss, so I presumed that "24 hours max" applied.

Comment: @Nickson, yes, that follows. In your original code the datatype is a string; in this revision, the datatype is "Time".